# Route Express Manipulate

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a question.

Can I manipulate routes at Express?. When i give a get or post requisition to address Can I pass 2 routes to same get or post requisition?
Something like This.

```
module.exports = function (app) {

var controller  = app.controllers.maps.cliente;

app.route('/clientes')

/* Something like this 
.get(verificaAutenticacao, controller.listaClientesRegionais)
.get(verificaAutenticacao, controller.listaClientes)
*/
// OR
/* Something like this 
 .get(verificaAutenticacao, controller.listaClientesRegionais, 
  controller.listaClientes)

 */

 .post(verificaAutenticacao, controller.atualizaCoordenadas);

  app.route('/clientes/:id')
.get(verificaAutenticacao, controller.obtemCliente);
};
```

Comment: The Express version is 4.8.8

Answer (score 1):

You can call same method from both routes because there is no way to manipulate routes in ExpressJS framework.

Comment: When I call the same method the application call only first line and not the both. and I need use the both.

Answer (score 0):

I found method Next(), which can do a bypass. But I don't know how to use it.

Code:

```
var controller = app.controllers.maps.cliente;

var listaCli = function (req, res, next) 
{
  controller.listaClientes();
  controller.listaRegionais();
  next();
};

 app.route('/clientes/')    
 .get(verificaAutenticacao, listaCli)
```

When I try to use it happens

```
  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection 
  id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined.
```

I don't know if mongoDB causes this or because syntax with Express.